# Method not found - google protobuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I changed a data type in .proto message as follows:

```
message a { int64 b = 1; }
```

to

```
message a { string b = 1; }
```

and i am getting

> method not found.

Then I tried changing the field number from '1' to '2', still getting same error

Comment: What happens if you try your original code but with `2`. i.e. `message a { int64 b = 2; }`.   In otherwords don't change two things at once

Comment: when do you get that error? proto compile, application compile, or application runtime?

Comment: application runtime

Comment: when i changed only one thing, i.e data type from int32 to string, i got the same error

Comment: have you run protoc?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like `string`?

Comment: The error sounds like you haven't fully/properly regenerated and rebuilt all layers of the application. However: note, I'd you have pre-existing data you want to be able to load, changing the data type like this is not valid - I would expected a runtime error about an invalid tag, though, not a missing method